# If statements into Array

Tags: shell, shell-script

I'd like to ask if below code (multiple if statements) can be converted into array? Here:

```sh
if [ "$(egrep -l 'NU.PRODUCT' $LINE)" ]; then
    VALUE='PRODUCT'
elif [ "$(egrep -il 'NU.SERVICE' $LINE)" ]; then
    VALUE='SERVICE'
elif [ "$(egrep -il 'NU.COMMERCE' $LINE)" ]; then
    VALUE='COMMERCE'
elif [ "$(egrep -il 'NU.EDUCATION' $LINE)" ]; then
    VALUE='EDUCATION'
else
    VALUE='OTHERS'
fi
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by converting them into an array. Can you clarify what you want?

Comment: I want to ask if above if statements can be done using array instead of using if statements and how?

Comment: What is the content of the file whose name is the value of `LINE`?

Comment: how about `typeset -u VALUE; VALUE="$(egrep -oi 'product|service|commerce|education' $LINE)"; :${VALUE:=others}`

Comment: @patrick, it works but another questions is, how about when there were some modifications. Please refer to above question above.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot use `if` statements at all? If this is a puzzle or assignment, please tell us all the constraints.